# EF Core Compress Decompress Column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

As an example take a simple poco with an **ID** and a string property called **data**.

What would be the best way to call `COMPRESS(data)` before saving the entity using **EF Core** and calling `DECOMPRESS(data)` on loading it. The database column of course would be VARBINARY.

*Detailed:*

Writing custom SQL to achieve this (based on the above example) would look like this:

```
SELECT Id, DECOMPRESS(@Data) as [Data]
FROM table
```

for selecting and like this for inserting an entity:

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES(@Id, COMPRESS(@Data))
```

*Notes:*

It's SQL Server.

The current string length can go up to a few thousand, as such a fixed-length `NVARCHAR` using PAGE or ROW compression on the DB side are not an option.

Comment: You could try using a [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) But then you have to compress/decompress using c# code instead of SQL server methods.

Comment: I considered that option, similarly, I could simply compress the value before storing it, however as SQL Server has an option to compress and decompress I was wondering if there would be a way to configure EF core.

Comment: to whoever voted for a close, what exactly is not clear within this question?

Comment: You could call `SELECT COMPRESS(@Data)` in your conversions, but I wouldn't suggest doing this.  Because it will be a performance nightmare. 

Other options would be to have a view to query the decompressed data a and a storedprocedure to insert/update the compressed data.

Comment: Take a look at this. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727711/5817136

Answer (score 12):

Using a conversion seems the best way. Since the sooner you compress the data, the less network I/O your going to generate. Also compressing will burn precious SQL server CPU cycles and may impact the performance of the SQL server.

```
public class YourEntityTypeConfigruation : IEntityTypeConfiguration<YourEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<YourEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.Data)
            .HasConversion(
                v => Zip(v),
                v => Unzip(v));
    }
    
    public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

        int cnt;

        while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {
            dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] Zip(string str) {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
                //msi.CopyTo(gs);
                CopyTo(msi, gs);
            }

            return mso.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes) {
        using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (var mso = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
                //gs.CopyTo(mso);
                CopyTo(gs, mso);
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Using the SQL server methods is possible when you create a view like

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT Id, DECOMPRESS(Data) as [Data]
FROM table
```

And [mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#example) it in EF Context

For insert/updates you would need stored procedures to compress the data. Beating the purpose of using entity framework to track changes to entities.